# How can I forward class methods in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, proxy, forwarding

In Objective-C I know you can forward selectors from one instance to another:

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
```

How can I also forward class methods to another class? `resolveClassMethod:` didn't seem appropriate, because I don't want to dynamically add methods to my class, just forward the calls.

Edit: So far the best I have is to create an instance that forwards its selector to a class object, like this:

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    return NSClassFromString(@"TheClass");
}
```

Its just a little uglier, because the proxy object has to accept instance methods, so the proxy has to declare instance methods for the class methods it is proxying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Objective-C a class object is just an object like any other and support forwarding in the same way. What you are looking for is:

```
+ (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```